# how to export text between strings from text file

Tags: python, grep

I have a long text file containing product descriptions like these

```
Item code 104
Product name a
Description number 1
Description number 1 extra lines

Item code 108
Product name b
Description number 2
```

I would like to export into files named after each product the text that includes the name and description, just the text between the item codes but not the item codes themselves.

In the example above I would like to have

file 1 a.txt 
containing :
product name a 
descrption 1

file 2 b.txt
containing :
product name b
description 2

I have been searching online and found something similar, but not exacly what I need.  The code that i found is in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222106/how-to-extract-information-between-two-unique-words-in-a-large-text-file).

Than question referred to numerous text files, whereas I need multimple instances found in the same file and save as a new file named after a line from what was read.

Comment: Show the 'something similar' that you have found, and what has to change to make it exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import re

ITEM_NONE  = 0
ITEM_FOUND = 1

state = ITEM_NONE

out_file = None

with open('/tmp/data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = re.match(r'^Item code (\d+)$', line)
        if m:
            state = ITEM_FOUND
            out_file = open('/tmp/%d.txt' % int(m.group(1)), 'w')

        m = re.match(r'^$', line)
        if m:
            state = ITEM_NONE 
            out_file.close()

        if state != ITEM_NONE:
            out_file.write(line)

if out_file:
    out_file.close()
```

Comment: I ran your code on python 2.7 and got the following error
`line 25, in <module>
    out_file.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: Then you have a black line before an line with 'Item code xxx' -  you add a similar check as the last two lines to line 25... Do you understand the above code  ?

Comment: sort of worked, but I had to modify `m = re.match(r'^$', line)` to `m = re.match(r'^xxx', line)` dont ask me why.
Also I wanted the file to be named after the second line, and it named it after the first.